# Multiple pandas users connecting to SQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

New to Pandas & SQL.  Haven't found an answer specific to this config, and not sure if standard SQL wisdom applies when introducing pandas to the mix.

Doing a school project that involves ~300 gb of data in ~6gb .csv chunks.

School advised syncing data via dropbox, but this seemed impractical for a 4-person team.

So, current solution is AWS EC2 & RDS instance (MySQL, I think it'll be, 1 table).

What I wanted to confirm before we start setting it up:

If multiple users are working with (and occasionally modifying) the data, can this arrangement manage conflicts?  e.g., if user A uses pandas to construct a dataframe from a query, are the records in that query frozen if user B tries to work with them?

My assumption is that the data in the frame are in memory, and the records in the SQL database are free to be modified by others until the dataframe is written back to the db, but I'm hoping that either I'm wrong or there's a simple solution here (like a random sample query for each user or something).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849551/compute-on-pandas-dataframe-concurrently  see this if helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `pandas` DataFrame object does not interact directly with the db. Once you read it in it sits in memory locally. You would have to use a method like `DataFrame.to_sql` to write your changes back to the MySQL DB. For more information on reading and writing to SQL tables, see the `pandas` documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

Comment: Got it - so it follows that users not coordinating their changes could overwrite one-another.  Will be sure & take appropriate cautions, in that case.