# How to carry out a function in parallel for a large df?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to carry out a function that searches through my dataframe and substitutes newer entries for older ones. My dataframe is dependant on players and their tickets, which means I have had to split the dataframe by players instead of by even sized chunks. The function works fine for smaller dataframes, but for a bigger one I have tried parallelising the function with the module "multiprocessing". The set-up I have carried out is as follows:

```
# Callback function for updating progress
def update_progress(result):
    with progress_lock:
        progress.value += 1
        print(f"Progress: {progress.value}/{num_chunks} chunks processed.")

def split_dataframe_by_player(df, num_chunks):
    grouped = df.groupby('PLAYER_ID')
    sorted_groups = sorted(grouped, key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
    chunks = [[] for _ in range(num_chunks)]

    for i, group in enumerate(sorted_groups):
        chunks[i % num_chunks].append(group[1])

    return [pd.concat(chunk) if chunk else pd.DataFrame() for chunk in chunks]

# Parallel processing function
def parallel_process(df, func):
    global df_chunks, progress, progress_lock
    num_cores = mp.cpu_count()
    df_chunks = split_dataframe_by_player(df, num_cores)

    progress = Value('i', 0)
    progress_lock = Lock()

    pool = mp.Pool(num_cores)
    results = [pool.apply_async(func, args=(chunk,), callback=update_progress) for chunk in df_chunks]

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return pd.concat([r.get() for r in results])
```

I don't think it has sped up my computing time as much, but I am new to multiprocessing so it might be a direct product of that. Let me know if I need to improve on my multiprocessing functions or if there are better options.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: create a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compute on pandas dataframe concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849551/compute-on-pandas-dataframe-concurrently)

Comment: As an aside: There is no need for `progress` to be a `Value`; it can be an `int` since it is only being accessed by the main process. Likewise, no need to update it under control of a lock since `update_progress` will not be called concurrently.